# Querying dynamo by time intervals

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm new to DynamoDB and would like some help on how to best structure things, and whether it's the right tool for the job.

Let's say I have thousands of users signed up to receive messages. They can choose to receive messages every half hour, hour, couple of hours or every 4 hours. So essentially there is a schedule attribute for each user's message. Users can also specify a time window for when they receive these messages, e.g. 09:00 - 17:00 and also toggle an active state.

I want to be able to easily get the messages to send to the various users at the right time.
If done in SQL this would be really easy, with something like:

```
Select * from UserMessageSchedules
where 
now() > startTime 
and now() < endTime
and userIsActive
and schedule = 'hourly'
```

But I'm struggling to do something similar in DynamoDB. At first I thought I'd have the following schema:

userId (partion Key)
messageId (sort key)
schedule (one of half_hour, hour, two_hours, four_hours)
startTime_userId
endTime

I'd create a Global Secondary Index with the 'schedule' attribute being the partition key, and startTime + userId being the sort key.
I could then easily query for messages that need sending after a startTime.
But I'd still have to check endTime > now() within my lambda. Also, i'd be reading in most of the table, which seems inefficient and may lead to throughput issues?
And with the limited number of schedules, would I get hot partitions on the GSI?

So I then thought rather than sending messages from a table designed to store users preferences, I could process this table when an entry is made/edited and populate a toSend table, which would look like this:

timeSlot (pk)   timeSlot_messageId (sk)
00:30           00:30_Message1_Id
00:30           00:30_Message2_Id
01:00           01:00_Message1_Id

Finding the messages to send at certain time would be nice and fast as I'd just query on the timeSlot
But again I'm worried about hot spots and throughput. Is it ok for each partition to have 1000's rows and for just that partition to be read? Are there any other problems with this approach?

Another possibility would be to have different tables (rather than partitions) for each half hour when something could be sent 
e.g, toSendAt_00:30, toSendAt_01:00, toSendAt_01:30
and these would have the messageId as the primary key and would contain the data needing to be sent. I'd just scan the table. Is this overkill?

Rather than do big reads of data every half an hour, would I be better duplicating the data into Elastic Search and querying this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the scale you are working on?

Comment: I'm expecting to be pushing out tens of thousands of messages around the start of each interval.
I've given this some more thought.
Trying to read 10k messages in the first few seconds of that interval would mean I'd have to set the RCU very high. Instead, I could read the data using pagination during the previous interval and put it into SQS ready to be sent, so the read throughput would be spread out.
I still don't know whether to use a table for each send interval though or if I should just use ES.

Comment: if your use case is to just get by key why not use redis instead of elastic search, it will certainly cost you lesser.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the way to go. Looks like I'll easily be able to query for messages to send at a certain time, but with none of the throttling, I'd get with DynamoDB.
https://www.redislabs.com/blog/get-sql-like-experience-redis/